# Delete Drag and Drop Behavior of IKImageBrowserView

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, finder, ikimagebrowserview

By default (it seems), IKImageBrowserView enables drag and drop to locations in the Finder.  I would like to turn off this behavior but am unsure of how to do so.  I was thinking that perhaps implementing the NSDraggingDestination protocol and overriding it could solve this, but so far it hasn't worked for me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The `NSDraggingDestination` protocol is exactly what it says: It's the protocol for being a drag *destination*. Implementing it or overriding it in the view class won't change anything about dragging *from* it; when the user does that, the view is the drag *source*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to customize IKImageBrowserView's drag and drop behavior, you can implement the `- (NSUInteger) imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *) aBrowser writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *) itemIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard` method in your browser's data source object.  That will let you define what types and data you want to put on the pasteboard when doing a drag.  If you want to disable dragging entirely, you should be able to just return 0 (the number of items you want to be dragged).

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting Lion you can subclass `IKImageBrowserView` and override the `draggingSession:sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:` [NSDraggingSource protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSDraggingSource) method. To prevent drags outside of your application just return `NSDragOperationNone` if the context is `NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication`. Otherwise, return the dragging operations that you're interested in. This way you can disallow drags to the desktop, Finder, etc. but still permit drags within your application's image browser view.

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context {
    [super draggingSession:session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:context];

    switch (context) {
        case NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication:
            return NSDragOperationNone;
            break;

        case NSDraggingContextWithinApplication:
            return NSDragOperationAll;
            break;

        default:
            return NSDragOperationAll;
            break;
    }
}
```